# skip div section when it is display none while displaying html content

Tags: jquery

I am looping through html content and displaying in other table. while reading, if div element is display:none then i want to skip the entire div section.

in the below example, need to hide "Property size, 100" row.

Please let me know the best option.

thanks you so much.

Surya.

```js
$('#tblWorksheet tbody').empty();
var tdworksheet;
 
$('#Worksheet label, #Worksheet input, #Worksheet select').each(function(index, element) { // context is 
  var theTag = this.tagName;
  var TF;
     
      if($(this).parent().get( 0 ).tagName == 'DIV' )
   {
            //hide entire div section          
   }
      
      if (theTag == "LABEL") {
        theValue = $(this).attr('title')

        if (theValue != null)
          tdworksheet += "<tr><td class='col-sm-2'><b>" + theValue + "</b></td>>"
      } else if (theTag == "INPUT" && this.type == 'text') {
        theValue = $(this).val();

        if (theValue != null)
          tdworksheet += "<td class='col-sm-2'><b>" + theValue + "</b></td></tr>"
      }
      });

$('#tblWorksheet tbody').append(tdworksheet);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblWorksheet" border=1>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>


<div id="Worksheet" class="divparent">

  <div>
    <p class="text-info" style="margin-left:10px;">
      Please enter the following deck information.
    </p>

  </div>

  <div class="row" id="divProp" style="display:none;">
    <div class=" col-md-5 text-right">
      <label title="Property Size">Property Size</label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
      <input class="form-control" id="propsize" name="PropSize" type="text" value="100" />
      
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row" id="divWorkType">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
      <label id="lblWorkType" title="WorkType">Work Type</label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
      <input Value="DISTURB" class="form-control" disabled="True" id="WORKTYPE" name="WORKTYPE" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hint: Use http://api.jquery.com/css/ to read the current display status of an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check visibility of a div using jQuery's `.is()` combined with the `:visible` selector. It looks like you also want to make sure it's a div, so your conditional would be something like this:

```
var $parent = $(this).parent();

if($parent.is('div') && !$parent.is(':visible')) {
    return true; // continue to next loop iteration
}
```

Comment: You are Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here the completed code.

```js
$('#tblWorksheet tbody').empty();
var tdworksheet;
 
$('#Worksheet label, #Worksheet input, #Worksheet select').each(function(index, element) { // context is 
  var theTag = this.tagName;
  var TF;
     
      if($(this).parent().is('div') && !$(this).parent().is(':visible'))
   {
              return true;         
   }
      
      if (theTag == "LABEL") {
        theValue = $(this).attr('title')

        if (theValue != null)
          tdworksheet += "<tr><td class='col-sm-2'><b>" + theValue + "</b></td>>"
      } else if (theTag == "INPUT" && this.type == 'text') {
        theValue = $(this).val();

        if (theValue != null)
          tdworksheet += "<td class='col-sm-2'><b>" + theValue + "</b></td></tr>"
      }
      });

$('#tblWorksheet tbody').append(tdworksheet);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblWorksheet" border=1>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>


<div id="Worksheet" class="divparent">

  <div>
    <p class="text-info" style="margin-left:10px;">
      Please enter the following deck information.
    </p>

  </div>

  <div class="row" id="divProp" style="display:none;">
    <div class=" col-md-5 text-right">
      <label title="Property Size">Property Size</label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
      <input class="form-control" id="propsize" name="PropSize" type="text" value="100" />
      
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row" id="divWorkType">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
      <label id="lblWorkType" title="WorkType">Work Type</label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
      <input Value="DISTURB" class="form-control" disabled="True" id="WORKTYPE" name="WORKTYPE" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```